# getting syntax error for else in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I started learning core java from youtube but while writing same code in eclipse   i am getting syntax error .

package Javatut;

public class ifelse {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int test = 10;

    if (test == 10);{


        System.out.println("yes");
        }

        else{ 
            System.out.println("No");
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: remove the semi-colon from the `if` statement

Comment: You have a semicolon between the if conditional and the block. Replace `if (test == 10);{` with `if (test == 10) {`.

Comment: I suggest you use an IDE, it will help you find syntax errors, format your code, compile, run and debug your program  and much, much more.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an IDE as this will help you find such issues.  After using the auto-formatter, I can see this warning in IntelliJ

[image]

You can see that the formatting is not what you think it should be as you have an extra `;` in your code.